# Regex Nested Quantifier *

Tags: c#, regex, comments

I am trying to use Regex to make a comment finder in text, but I get the error 'Nested Quantifier *'

```
Regex Comment = new Regex("/*.*?*/");
```

As in: It starts at `/*` and ends at `*/` [Comments]

What is the problem with doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because literal `*` must be escaped `\*`. Otherwise the regex engine take it for the quantifier * (zero or more time). The error message you obtain is relative to `*?*` (the regex engine see two consecutive quantifiers `*?` and `*`)

You can write your pattern like this:

```
Regex Comment = new Regex(@"(?s)/\*.*?\*/");
```

*(I added the `(?s)` modifier to allow the dot to match newlines)*